# Struts2: Save SQL query in the database

Tags: java, sql

In my Struts2 Java web application users are allowed to query the database. As an example, the user needs to get the employee details whose first name is equal to 'Charles'. Then s/he can select the report columns and criteria (firstname='Charles').

Once the user gives above inputs it need to save the relevant SQL query into the database.

```
e.g. SQL -> SELECT * FROM employee WHERE firstname='Charles'
```

Here is what I am trying in my action class.

```
try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                SelectAction.getDatabase(), SelectAction.getUser(),
                SelectAction.getPassword());

        if (connection != null) {

            System.out.println("Database connection established!");

            stmt = connection.createStatement();

            String sql = "INSERT INTO reports (report_id, sql) values ('" + reportId + "', '" + sqlQ + "');";
            System.out.println("sql--->" + sql);
            // Executing query
            stmt.executeQuery(sql);

            return SUCCESS;

        } else {
            System.out.println("----Failed to make connection!");
            return ERROR;
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Connection Failed!!");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return SUCCESS;
    }
```

This is my insert query.

```
INSERT INTO reports (report_id, sql) values ('mynewreport', 'SELECT * FROM employee WHERE firstname='Charles'');
```

I am getting following error in my console.

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "Charles"
```

I think here I am using a String so that the problem is with quotes('). I am using postgreSQL as database.

Any suggestions to solve this issue ?

Comment: If you are starting now, consider studying something 10 years newer, like JPA 2. [DAO is dead, long live JPA](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/jpa_ejb3_killed_the_dao).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Never** use string concatenation of user supplied values to build a SQL statement.
**Never** use string concatenation of any non-integer values to build a SQL statement.
You will leave yourself open to **[SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)** attacks and/or SQL statement errors.
Hackers will love you for allowing them to steal all your data, and the nefarious ones will corrupt or delete all your data, while laughing maniacally at you on their way to the bank.

Use `PreparedStatement` and parameter markers.

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO reports (report_id, sql) values (?, ?)";
try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    stmt.setString(1, reportId);
    stmt.setString(2, sqlQ);
    stmt.executeUpdate();
}
```